# Routing 2 components with same lazy load modules

Tags: angular, parameters, module, routes, lazy-loading

I have BookModules, and 2 components BookCreate and BookEdit. 
How to differentiate them when I use lazyload modules.
Suppose that I have 2 buttons create and edit in homepage. I want to click each button will navigate to bookCreate/bookEdit component

I want like that: myweb/store/book -> BookCreateComponent myweb/profile/12345/edit -> BookEditComponent 
in HomeRoutes

```
      {
        path: 'book',
        loadChildren: 'app/run/run.module#BookModule'
      }
```

In BookRoutes

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: BookCreateComponent
  }
  // I don't know how routing to BookEditComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this my example:

#### Module:

```js
use any option 1 or 2
    1) {
        path: "profile",
        loadChildren: "app/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule"
    },
    2) {
        path: "profile",
        loadChildren: "./profile/profile.module#ProfileModule"
    },
```

#### ProfileRoutes

```js
    {
       path: '',
       component: ProfileComponent
    }
    {
       path: ':id',
       component: BookCreateComponent
    }
    {
       path: ':id/edit',
       component: BookEditComponent
    }
```

#### Template:

```html
  <a [routerLink]="['/profile/'+ user_id]">create</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/profile/' + user_id +'/edit']">edit</a>
```

Comment: I want like that: myweb/store/book -> BookCreateComponent myweb/profile/12345/edit -> BookEditComponent If use that, above code will not work, right?

Comment: updated answer please check and if any query then add comment.

Comment: hi @Savaj if use your solution, my site will be:
myweb/profile/12345/book/edit NOT myweb/profile/12345/edit

Comment: hi @Savaj, I mean I want url will be: myweb/profile/12345/edit (without book).
I have BookModule will be lazy load with 2 Modules: StoreModules and ProfileModules
with store I want:  myweb/store/book
with profile :  myweb/profile/12345/edit

Comment: thank for your helps, but I didn't see lazy load module with BookModules here.
Can't we use lazyload modules here, right? Just import component like your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, i would add a second route to the BookModule:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: BookCreateComponent
  },      
  {
    path: 'edit',
    component: BookEditComponent
  }
```

Then you can route to it like that:

```
[routerLink]="book/edit" -> BookEditComponent
[routerLink]="book" -> BookCreateComponent
```

Comment: I want like that: myweb/store/book -> BookCreateComponent myweb/profile/12345/edit -> BookEditComponent If use that, above code will not work, right?